# TreeView children's margin in WPF

Tags: wpf, treeview, wpf-controls

I'm writing the WPF app that uses TreeView control inside the UserControl. TreeView control has the same width as the UserControl.

The problem is that I need to make the children nodes to have the full with of the TreeView. I can't assign the width by the static expression as well as UserControl that contains TreeView may have variable width.

I thought that the solution can be reached by assigning the TreeView child item the width of the UserControl. But if I do so the TreeView child item will be out of control, as well as there is margin in the children item. For example

`Item A`

`---Item B`

Can you tell, how can I get the width of --- ? Or to make ItemB be under the Item A without using static margin metrics?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some code of what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Style of TreeViewItem and make its Horizontal Alignment as Stretch instead of Left. Also ensure you host your ContentPresenter inside the Grid.

In this case, eventhough the header text seems to be leeser in width, the mouse hover or Selected color will cover the entire width of treeview. I hope that is what you need.